# Stereo bar 40 cm or 70 cm?

Tags: stereo

Hi,

I'm about to buy a rycote stereo bar to use it with my kit of oktavas. This should provide me a quite versatile set up for stereo recordings (X/Y, ORTF, A/B).

The rycote bar comes in two sizes 40 cm and 70 cm. As I'm not really quite familiar with AB techniques, I would like to know if I would really need the extra 30 cm from the 70 cm bar. In which situations this could be useful?

The price difference between the two is almost irrelevant but for portability I'm thinking of going with the smaller one.

Comment: Do you see any advantages of the Grace Design Spacebar over the Rycote? There is a significant difference in price.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend reading [this article](http://www.dpamicrophones.com/en/Mic-University/StereoTechniques.aspx) before making your decision. A lot of useful info about AB mic placement etc..

I think you'd be fine with 40cm unless you want a wide AB image from a pair of omnis. I'd also consider the [Grace Design Spacebar](http://www.gracedesign.com/products/spacebar/spacebar_stereo.html) as well as the Rycote.

Comment: Do you see any advantages of the Grace Design Spacebar over the Rycote?


Comment: It is more expensive, but it's a smartly thought out modular system, making it easy to expand your setup down the road into say an LCR setup or a Decca tree. Their stereo bar also tilts up or down. I am a big fan of Grace, having owned their portable Lunatec V3 for years. It's built like a tank.

Answer (score 1):

Go with the 40 cm version, if the AB really needs to be wider, just use an extra mic stand.
(i know a mic stand is bigger than a 70 cm stereo bar, but i always bring a small spare stand just in case)